# Excel Min IF Not Equal to

Tags: excel-formula, excel-2007

I'm banging my head off a desk trying to use a simple formula.

I've used MIN IF and MAX IF many times however I now want to use it where my operator is not equal to (<>) and it just doesn't like me.

I have a list of categories where "Unknown" is usually the lowest percentage but wants to be excluded from this return.
It is currently returning Unknowns percentage but will return another categories if it is lower

Part of the formula causing me headaches

```
=MIN(IF('STP% Division'!$K:$K<>"Unknown",'STP% Division'!$L:$L))
```

Overall Formula

```
=ROUND(MIN(IF('STP% Division'!$K:$K<>"Unknown",'STP% Division'!$L:$L))*100,0)&"%"
```

Help

Answer (score 0):

Got it, needed to be an Array Formula and wouldn't work on entire columns, just the specific range

```
=ROUND(MIN(IF('STP% Division'!$K4:$K11<>"Unknown",'STP% Division'!$L4:$L11))*100,0)
```

Confirmed with CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER instead of just ENTER, this looks like this in the cell - the braces around the whole formula are not entered manually.

```
{=ROUND(MIN(IF('STP% Division'!$K4:$K11<>"Unknown",'STP% Division'!$L4:$L11))*100,0)}
```